# how to show the created and updated date in django admin?

Tags: django, admin

Is it possible to access the created date and updated date from django admin page ? I don't have these fields specified in the model.

Comment: why dont you add that fields?

Comment: I already have some data in the db.. Need to get the created and update date for the existing data..

Comment: u can add that fields and have some default values for them. they will be added to database.

Comment: I need the real dates at which the instances are created

Comment: I cannot help with that, sorry have no clue.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't give concrete info, so i create a demo.

```
# models.py
class Comment(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


# admin.py
class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','body', 'created_date', 'updated_date')

admin.site.register(models.Comment,CommentAdmin)
```

[DateField.auto_now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now):

> Automatically set the field to now every time the object is saved. Useful for “last-modified” timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override.

[DateField.auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add):

> Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created. Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override. So even if you set a value for this field when creating the object, it will be ignored. If you want to be able to modify this field, set the following instead of auto_now_add=True:

Comment: I haven't added the fields initially to the models and I have some data in the DB.. Is it possible to get the created and updated date?

Comment: No. If you didn't have those fields in the model originally, there's no way to populate them accurately when adding them to records after the fact.

Comment: For reference, I usually create a model helper that contains these 2 fields, then subclass it for all my other models, thus guaranteeing this data always exists.

Comment: No option to get it django admin default fields also?

Comment: @kkr direct access django admin default fields.

Comment: How can I access the django admin fields ? Do they have created and updated date?

Comment: No, you didn't access fileds without registering in models, the right way access them just register in models.